# Add value to jsonb existing key and update others postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How can I add values to jsonb key ?
Example `

```
{"drivers": "15","updatedat":"someDate"}
```

after upd must be

```
{"drivers":"15,...,26","updatedat":"nowTime"}
```

updatedat inserted from node,so there is no problem,I can select value of derivers in node,add new and update,Is there other way make it with 1 query without using node?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, you just need `jsonb_set`:

```
t=# select jsonb_set('{"drivers": "15","updatedat":"someDate"}'::jsonb, '{updatedate}'::text[],to_jsonb(now()));
                                          jsonb_set
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"drivers": "15", "updatedat": "someDate", "updatedate": "2018-05-29T15:49:41.772188+00:00"}
(1 row)
```

unless you have older version of course...

**update** to change drivers att value:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"drivers": "15","updatedat":"someDate"}'::jsonb))
select jsonb_set(j,'{drivers}'::text[],to_jsonb(j->>'drivers'||',...,26')) from c;
                     jsonb_set
---------------------------------------------------
 {"drivers": "15,...,26", "updatedat": "someDate"}
(1 row)
```

Comment: nope,I want to add values to drivers without using porg. languages